# Adding JDBC driver to classpath on Raspberry pi

Tags: java, jdbc, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How do I add the JDBC driver to the class path on a java program I have on my raspberry pi? The class should compile correctly when I go to compile it on the raspberry pi board it just gives the error like it would when there is no driver present.
My class is called checker.java 
and it uses jdbc!

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For example, if you are in folder, where you have both your .java and .jar files:

```
javac -cp “jdbcdriver.jar” checker.java
```

By the way, class names must start with uppercase letter.

UPD:
You should run your program the same way

```
java -cp “jdbcdriver.jar” checker
```

Comment: hi , where do i download the jdbc driver from? i have this downloaded at the minute, 
mysql-connector-java-5.1.36 and my java comiple is javac -cp ".:mysql-connector-java-5.1.36:/opt/pi4ji/lib/*" i dont get any errors on running my code other than no suitable  jdbc driver found - how do i combat this! thanks