# Adding JDBC driver in raspberry pi

Tags: java, linux, jdbc, raspberry-pi3

I'm creating bots for discord and I execute them on my rpi. I want to use a database, in my case JavaDB and I always get the error message, that there isn't a driver. 
I figured out that I need to add JDBC somewhere on my rpi and I found this:
[Adding JDBC driver to classpath on Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443125/adding-jdbc-driver-to-classpath-on-raspberry-pi)
My question now: 
Is it possible to add the driver to all my .jar files (they are in different directorys) or have I to do something different?
How can I do it?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: How do you execute (start) your java processes?

Comment: I'm using this screen thing, but generally with `java -jar MyProgram.jar`
`

Comment: In that case, you need to add the driver to the `Class-Path` entry of your jar manifest, and the actual driver jar in a location relative to your own jar, or you need to build a fatjar/uberjar by including the classes and other files of the driver in your own jar.

Comment: So I just have to put the driver inside my project and generate e.g. a shaded jar?

Comment: How do you handle other dependencies in your project? It works the same. Be aware that shading a JDBC driver is not always the best course of action, it might break things.

Comment: I'm using maven. I did some research and it seems like I can't add it the usual way... is there a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: Asking for resources like tutorials is off-topic. And if it wasn't, that question is rather unspecific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start/run a java application, you do need to set a classpath. This classpath should then contain the driver. If the driver is on the classpath, you can use it inside your own applications.

You can add the given jdbc driver (jar-file) to the classpath via the

```
java -classpath classpath1;classpath2 MainClass
```

command. This is not rpi specific, but a java detail. Usually this is done using a script (bash or something similar), which is used to start the application.

Comment: Thank you a lot, is there a possibility to add the driver inside my .jar?

Comment: Why would you like to do something like this? You could generate a meta-jar which contains the classes of your own application and the classes of the jdbc jar-file. This could be done eg. by using the maven shade plugin.

Comment: One last question: Where can I get the JDBC driver from?

Comment: Obviously this depends on the database. Take a look at mvn repository.com to search for jar files.

Comment: Okay, this worked. I guess there are all drivers on mvn repository.com...